# Magento 2 Attribute option value not showing in custom theme phtml file

Tags: magento2

I have create a Magento Theme and also add attribute with a drop-down option value.

Now I wanted to display the value of the attribute in my `Magento_theme::advancesearch.phtml` file.
i use in my `advancesearch.phtml`

```
/**
 * Get attribute info by attribute code and entity type
 */ 
$attributeCode = 'color';
$entityType = 'catalog_product';

$objectManager =  \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

/*$attributeInfo = $objectManager->get(\Magento\Eav\Model\ResourceModel\Entity\Attribute\Collection::class)
                               ->setCodeFilter($attributeCode)
                               ->getFirstItem();*/

$attributeInfo = $objectManager->get(\Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute::class)
                               ->loadByCode($entityType, $attributeCode);

//var_dump($attributeInfo->getData()); exit;

/**
 * Get all options name and value of the attribute
 */ 
$attributeId = $attributeInfo->getAttributeId();
$attributeOptionAll = $objectManager->get(\Magento\Eav\Model\ResourceModel\Entity\Attribute\Option\Collection::class)
                                    ->setPositionOrder('asc')
                                    ->setAttributeFilter($attributeId)                                               
                                    ->setStoreFilter()
                                    ->load();

//var_dump($attributeOptionAll->getData()); exit;

/**
 * Fetch particular option's name and value of the attribute
 */
$optionId = YOUR_OPTION_ID;                                  
$attributeOptionSingle = $objectManager->get(\Magento\Eav\Model\ResourceModel\Entity\Attribute\Option\Collection::class)
                                       ->setPositionOrder('asc')
                                       ->setAttributeFilter($attributeId)
                                       ->setIdFilter($optionId)
                                       ->setStoreFilter()
                                       ->load()
                                       ->getFirstItem();

//var_dump($attributeOptionSingle->getData()); exit;
```

But this showing nothing to my theme. Here is my default.xml,

```
<container name="header_advance_search" as="header_advance_search" label="header custom" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="advance_search">  
                <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="advance_search" as="advance_search" template="Magento_Theme::advance_search.phtml"></block>
        </container>
        <move element="advance_search" destination="store.menu"/>
```

In Magento 1 I can use Mage: and get value of attribute product information and many more in any phtml file on Theme. But here face problem.
Is there any solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose i have a attribute like `color` and its options are `red, blue, yellow`.

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$attr_code = 'color';
$attribute = $objectManager->create('\\Magento\\Catalog\\Model\\Product\\Attribute\\Repository')->get($attr_code);

/*returns all options red, blue, yellow*/
$options = $attribute->getOptions();

if($options){
    foreach($options as $option){
        echo $option->getValue(); // get id of option
        echo $option->getLabel(); // get Label of option
    }
}
```

if you want to get the option text (Option Label) using option id eg: 11 is the id of yellow.

```
//get option text (Option Label) using option id
$optionId = 11;
$optionText = $attribute->getSource()->getOptionText($optionId);
echo $optionText; // return string 'yellow'.

//get option id using option label.
$optionText = 'yellow';
$optionId = $attribute->getSource()->getOptionId($optionText);
echo $optionId; // 11.
```

Comment: Its working, Please help me another thing, In magento we can use mage:: in anywhere any phtml file and get magento data for every sector, but is there possible to use that like mage: in magento 2?

Comment: No, in magento2 have no mage:: class,  recommend to use dependency injection in block, helper then use it in needed phtml.